# How to get a value of HandlerAspect's `CtxOut` type in request processing

Tags: scala, zio-http

In `zio-http`, one has the option to write middleware that provide some sort of context around a request; as a concrete example, we might think of an auth middleware that looks up some package of session information before processing a request:

```scala
case class UserSession(sessionId: UUID, username: String)

val authMiddleware: HandlerAspect[Any, UserSession] = HandlerAspect.customAuthProvidingZIO {  request =>
  ZIO.succeed(request.headers.get("X-Session-ID").flatMap {
    case None => ZIO.succeed(None)
    case Some(sessionId) => fetchSession(sessionId).catchAll(_ => ZIO.succeed(None))
  }
}
```

We can attach this middleware to a `Routes` to ensure that any request coming in with no `X-Session-ID` header, or a session ID that our session cache doesn't know about, gets rejected. My question is, if the middleware succeeds in producing a `UserSession`, how can I get that value and use it in the request handler, something like

```scala
// this doesn't work
Routes(
  Method.GET / "foo" -> handler { (userSession: UserSession, request: Request) =>
    fooDatabase.getAll(userSession.username)
  }
) @@ authMiddleware
```

One reason this doesn't work, of course, is that the middleware isn't even attached to the `Routes` until after it's created, so there's something of a chicken-and-egg problem; but that seems to be kinda the point of middleware, and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/zio/zio-http/issues/1761) and [this PR](https://github.com/zio/zio-http/pull/2011) have *titles* at least that suggest that they're trying to achieve something similar to this, though I don't see anything exactly like what I'm looking for in the PR code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching the middleware/`HandlerAspect` to the "outside" of the `Routes` as in the snippet in the question, it turns out that it's possible to reference the middleware in the definition of each `Route` itself:

```scala
val authMiddleware: HandlerAspect[Any, UserSession] = ???
Routes(
  Method.GET / "foo" -> authMiddleware -> handler { (userSession: UserSession, request: Request) =>
    ...business logic goes here... }
)
```

(Kudos to user `zzyzzyxx` on the ZIO Discord for this find.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do that is to go through the ZIO environment.
Assuming you have `authMiddleware: HandlerAspect[Any, UserSession]` and `routes: Routes[UserSession, Err]`, you can turn the latter into a `Routes[Any, Err]` by calling the following on it:

```scala
      .transform: handler =>
         authMiddleware.applyHandlerContext:
            Handler.fromFunctionZIO: (userSession, req) =>
              handler(req).provideLayer(ZLayer.succeed(userSession))
```

But at this point I can't help but wonder why I should even bother with the whole `HandlerAspect` thing.